# Tensorflow Build error

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, bazel, tensorflow-serving

Hey I am new to Tenserflow, I got the tenserflow code from git (https://github.com/tensorflow/serving) and when i tried to build it-using the steps in the documentation-I was getting this error:

> ERROR:
>   com.google.devtools.build.lib.packages.BuildFileContainsErrorsException:
>   error loading package '': Extension file not found. Unable to load
>   package for '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow:workspace.bzl': BUILD file
>   not found on package path. INFO: Elapsed time: 0.081s

Comment: Are you sure you want Serving and not Tensorflow? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow

Comment: yes, I am working on a  neural net and I am trying to serve it and I am using the tutorial from the docs to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you have not cloned recursively (`git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/tensorflow/serving`) so TensorFlow does not get cloned as a submodule and Bazel cannot find TensorFlow itself.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/g3doc/setup.md#clone-the-tensorflow-serving-repository